# using val in kotlin lambda

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

i'm playing around with map in kotlin, and currently I would like to see whether it would be possible to map a list of integers to a list of functions (Int) -> Int, while doing a bunch of operations inside the lambda that would require me to save values to vals

So I have this simple code:

```
val num = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4)

  val funcs = num.map <Int, (Int) -> Int > { x  -> {
        y -> y + x
    }}
```

This is a bit of a condensed example, the thing i'm really trying to do is a bit more convoluted. But I need to quite a bit of operations inside of of the 'inner' lambda, so I need to write codeblocks where I can use val. Like this:

```
val fs = num.map <Int, (Int) -> Int > { x  -> {
        y -> {
        val tmp = y *2
        val tmp1 = x / 2
        tmp + tmp1

        }
}}
```

But this part doesnt work, the compiler is confused by return types
How can I do something like this?

Comment: what part doesn't work?

Comment: also why do you need intermediary variables? what's wrong with `y -> y * 2 + x / 2`?

Comment: the exact example is a toy example. But really I just need to write some code that will we infeasible to write in a single oneliner

Comment: Have you tried specifying explicit types for the lambda params?

Comment: Also, the bottom part doesnt work

Comment: yes, in the inner one no luck. Also tried paranteses around the argument in the inner lambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code in particular does not work is because you are adding an extra `{` after `y ->` in the second example:

```
val fs = num.map<Int, (Int) -> Int> { x ->
    { y ->
        { // this is not needed
            val tmp = y * 2
            val tmp1 = x / 2
            tmp + tmp1
            
        }// this is not needed
    }
}
```

So you are creating a "block" of `{}` which in kotlin means that you are creating a lambda function. The reason block is in quotes is because if you truly want a block in kotlin the syntax is `run {}`, as opposed to the java `{}`. But again, you do not need it here.

All you have to do is remove the extra brackets and your code is fine:

```
val fs = num.map <Int, (Int) -> Int > { x  -> {
        y ->
    val tmp = y *2
    val tmp1 = x / 2
    tmp + tmp1
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between single-line and multi-line lambda

```
val fs = num.map { x ->
    { y: Int ->
        val tmp = y * 2
        val tmp1 = x / 2
        tmp + tmp1
    }
}
```